# Does anyone know how to access *Native* Sound Notifications in Flex Mobile, or the devices "audio" state?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, audio, vibration, air-native-extension

Does anyone know of an AIR Native Extension (ANE) that allows you to access the device's notification sound(s)?  OR, a method to query if the device is in "silent" or "vibrate" mode?

I've set up Push Notifications, but no sound plays on my (Android) device.

I know I can play my own sounds, but I want to use the native notification sound (the same as an SMS or email alert sound) and I don't want the sound to play if it shouldn't (viz. silent mode / vibrate mode).

I've been looking for hours and there's a "Vibrate ANE," and others looking for the same type of capability, but I haven't found anything usable for native sound notifications.

I believe that iOS automatically will play a notification sound when it receives a push notification (I think), but Android just flashes the "shade title" & shows the app's icon for the notification.

Maybe someone else has stumbled across a solution??? =)

Many Thanks!
Todd =D

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I need to find out if the device is in silent mode so my app stays silent too. I'm hoping an upvote will help.

Comment: You might check this site out here: http://extensionsforair.com/native-extensions/page/3/?orderby=downloads&order=DESC There's a "Silent Swithc" ANE that might expose what you're looking for & another on page 1 (I think).

Comment: You can also keep an eye on this list: http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/air-native-extension/
there's some overlap, but wha'da ya gonna do... =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to be careful attempt to access the built in sounds on iOS.

We definitely could write an extension that played any of the system sounds. However I believe these sounds are copyrighted, and my understanding of the Apple ToS is that your application may get rejected from the AppStore if you use them directly.

This is why things like a notifications extension only use a "default notification" value to access system sounds that are set by the user. These sounds are played on certain system events.

The sounds are all accessed via undocumented IDs: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

So yeah we’ve been very cautious of writing anything that could put developers in trouble with the AppStore. You have enough problems getting apps through as is. But if you read otherwise let me know.